# Correct drawable folder for SVG assets

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I assume the correct folder is drawable-nodpi.

I just need to know this so that I can set up PNGexpress in Photoshop to generate the folder automatically (on asset export) and know that im not forcing my developers to move the files around a bunch on their end.

Fire and forget type approach - best to be sure than assume though!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you create the SVG from inside of Android Studio it puts the file inside the drawable folder. You can check it here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html in the 7 step of the section "Adding a material icon".

So, with this, I would choice to use the drawable folder to keep the same behavior as Android Studio.

Comment: Do you know what it auto-names the folder?

Comment: @NukeouT I did not understand your question.

Comment: I guess im calling it the "drawable-nodpi" folder for now, until I hear otherwise or learn that that does not work